# wrap output of rdd.saveAsTextFile with values in pyspark

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark

Wondering how to "wrap" the results of `saveAsTextFile` with strings in pyspark.

I am attempting to write XML strings from an RDD to multiple files, specifically, as many partitions as there are in the RDD.  I have done this successfully with something like:

```py
import math, uuid

# number of records per page
perpage = 100 

# write to files
df.select('document').rdd.repartition(math.ceil(df.count()/perpage)).map(lambda row: row.document.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>','')).saveAsTextFile('file:///foo/bar/output/%s' % str(uuid.uuid4()))
```

For an RDD with 285 rows -- as an example -- this results in 3 `part-0000#` files, which is fine.  Each, looks like this:

```xml
<foo>
    <bar>amazing strings</bar>
</foo>
<foo>
    <bar>amazing strings2</bar>
</foo>
<foo>
    <bar>amazing strings3</bar>
</foo>
...
...
```

However, as a whole, this is not valid XML as this file would need a root tag.  I'd like something like...

```xml
<scrog>
    <foo>
        <bar>amazing strings</bar>
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <bar>amazing strings2</bar>
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <bar>amazing strings3</bar>
    </foo>
    ...
    ...
</scrog>
```

I understand that I could prepend `<scrog>` and append `</scrog>` to the text file after the fact, but I would like to better understand the use `saveAsTextFile`, and whether or not that would be an option.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using the spark-xml package?

Comment: @philantrovert I did, but unless I'm misunderstanding its utility, don't think it's what I'm looking for.  My understanding is that parses XML into a usable DataFrame, which can be re-serialized to XML.  That's great in some scenarios, but I don't need to parse, just write XML from strings that are ready for writing.